# PIVOT combined tables with criteria in sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

[image]

I want to show the result that returns all rows that has both a work and a home number

RESULT

[image]

I have written this SQL but it shows all. How do I show only to appear those with both values in home and work number and not showing the null values. I have tried adding WHERE PHONE_NUM IS NOT NULL but it did not work. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
WITH TABLE1 AS (

   SELECT

      P.ID,
      P.NAMES,
      P.DIGIT,
      Q.NUM_TYP,
      Q.PHONE_NUM
   FROM

      dbo.TABLE1 P
      INNER JOIN dbo.TABLE2 Q
         ON P.ID = Q.ID
)

SELECT *
FROM

TABLE1

   PIVOT (Max(PHONE_NUM) FOR NUM_TYP IN (HOME, WORK)) R
 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results from just table 2 using conditional aggregation:

```
select t2.id,
       max(case when t2.num_type = 'HOME' then phone_num end) as home,
       max(case when t2.num_type = 'WORK' then phone_num end) as work
from dbo.TABLE2 t2
group by t2.id
having max(case when t2.num_type = 'HOME' then phone_num end) is not null and
       max(case when t2.num_type = 'WORK' then phone_num end) is not null;
```

You can join table 1 to get other fields if you like.

Comment: @Jenna . . . Just join to the first table to get the additional information you want.  I note that in the answer.

Comment: I got it. Thanks so much.